# Step up converter problem PAM2423AECADJR

Tags: pcb-design, step-up

[image]

I have problem with a step up converter made with the PAM2423AECADJR.

I have an input to the converter 3-3.7 VDC and regulated the output to be 5 VDC.

I am driving a DC motor (1.5A max) with the 5 VDC, using in between an ATTINY85 that drives a motor driver with PWM.

The problem happens when I force the motor and exceeds 300 mA. Then everything becomes unstable and nothing works correctly, the motor starts to vibrate like crazy.

I am thinking that a problem could be with the fixed inductor.

Can anyone help me out?

This is the [link for the IC.](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/diodes%20inc._pam242x-1164328.pdf)

This is the BOM :
[image]

Comment: Johny Arduino - Hi, Please [edit] your question and add: (a) the datasheet link for the IC, (b) your schematic, (c) your BOM (especially, but not only, exact p/n and datasheets for the inductor and the motor), (d) your PCB  layout, and (e) some photos of your actual hardware. Thanks.

Comment: My guess without both schematic and layout is same as always, poor layout, insufficient decoupling and/or lack of freewheeling diode.

Comment: You would receive more help if you actually provided some details. Please post schematics, PCB layout and component BOM.

Comment: Hello to all ! Thank you for reaching out. I have uploaded the schematic and the link for the IC.

Comment: _"I am driving a DC motor (1.5A max)"_ - Which motor? What is its DC resistance? _"The problem happens when I force the motor and exceeds 300 mA. Then everything becomes unstable"_ - what happens if you replace the motor with a resistor that draws ~1.5A @ 5V (ie. ~3.3 Ohms)?

Comment: Hello Abbot, I haven't tried to put a resistor instead of the motor. These are the characteristics of the motor Characteristics
Terminal resistance 7.29 Ω
Terminal inductance 282 mH

Comment: I'm going to agree with @winny that layout/decoupling may be the issue, but it looks like you just copied the compensation components from the datasheet example, which has a different operating point.  I'd measure the open loop response to see what your phase margin looks like, or look at the response to a step load to see if you're on the edge of instability.

Comment: Guys, speak English hahaha , I am a software engineer and don't have huge knowledge from PCB's

I understand a lot to make basic things, but when it comes to more complicated, I am not that good :)

Comment: Is it possible to have an issue with the ATTINY85 ? It seems like it is resetting.

Comment: Hello to all! I was thinking that the width of the power lines might be the problem. Because they are very thin for this current.